# Laravel Page isn't working after fresh install

Tags: amazon-ec2, laravel-5, installation

I am a front end developer so don't hang me up please. Managed till now to install a new copy of Laravel on AWS EC2 server without issues several times for different projects.

Now I already tried installing this 3 times and tried to fallow up on every solution I could find to solve the error below, but still getting:

> [Tue Jan 24 10:19:49.885900 2017] [:error] [pid 14096] [client 92.27.88.79:56096] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Steps taken for install:

1. Setup a new instance of AWS EC2 -> create & generate security groups and keys -> connect using putty and the created key
2. Install apache2 on the instance created using:
   sudo apt-get install apache2
3. Install PHP7 & PHP mcrypt using:
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
   sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install php7.0
   sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
4. Install MySQL Server
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server
5. Install Git
   sudo apt-get install git-core
6. Install Laravel
   sudo git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
7. Install Composer
   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
   went to the root folder of Laravel (/var/www/nameOfProject)
   run command: php composer.phar install
8. Change folder access
   changed to 777 to be sure folder: laravel/storage
   changed to 777 to be sure folder: laravel/bootstrap
9. Restarted everything

I also tried again composer install and composer update and mostly anything that I could find on the internet; still didn't manage to get rid of this error.
If anything else I can provide to help figure this out, please do let me know.

Greatly appreciated any guidance or references to solutions that could solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have content inside the vendor folder? From which directory did you run composer update?

Comment: I don't even have the vendor folder. Any composer commands I run them in  /var/www/laravel

Comment: What is the composer update output? Composer command  should create vendor folder if there isn't one. Try removing composer.lock and then run composer update.

Comment: Hi Marin, you may want to add your last comment as an answer and then accept it so that anyone with a similar issue who comes across this thread will be able to quickly and easily see a possible solution to their issue. (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Glad you got it sorted, and good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I checked it all this time. I was not checking above the final composer confirmation for any errors; basically after I installed the php7 there were still some extensions missing I guess. So i just installed the fallowing: sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring, sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom, sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip. Also at the end I run again composer update and restarted the server. This fixed my problem. Thank you for your time!